# How can I store a 2 - 3 GB tree in memory and have it accessible to nodejs?

Tags: json, database, node.js

I have a large tree of data that I want to be able to efficiently access leaves, and efficiently serialize large chunks (10 - 20 MBs of it at a time) into json.

Right now I'm storing it as javascript objects, but I'm seeing garbage collection times of 4 - 5 seconds, which is not okay.

I tried using an embedded database (both sqlite and lmdb), but the performance overhead of going from rows to trees when I access data is prety high -- taking me 6 seconds to serialize 5 MBs into json.

Ideally I'd want to be able to tell v8 "please don't try to garbage collect that tree!"  (I tried turning GC off on the whole process, but I'm running a lightweight tcp server in front of it and that quickly started to run out of memory).

Or, maybe there's an embedded (or not embedded?) database that handles this natively that I don't know about.  (I do know about MongoDB -- it has a 16 MB limit on max object size though).

I'm thinking of maybe trying to pack the tree in a node buffer object (ie, basically simulate the v8 stack myself) but before I get that desperate I thought I'd ask stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Interesting question, can't you write code responding to the tree in C? Node.js can interact with native libraries.

Comment: I would say mongodb is a good idea. But you have to save the tree by nodes.  It is no good idea to save save the whole tree in one chunk. If the nodes are smaller than 16 MByte it would work. But mongodb has an asynchrounous access mechanism which makes it hard to implement tree traversion to find the leaves. Perhaps postgresql with a plv8 extension module installed could fit your needs. You can implement tree traversion using the javascript in stored procedures and probably you are able to use the btree indexes for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing large objects in a GC language is a bad practice. It is a problem in Java world as well. 
There are 2 solutions to this:

- Use an In Memory DB - like [Redis](http://redis.io/). See if you can leverage the data structure primitives Redis provides to your advantage.
- Go Native - NodeJS provides simple(comparatively) FFI, as half of the library is written in it. See the addons document [here](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) on how to proceed.

If you are deploying on server, then you have a 3rd option as well. Instead of linking native code directly with Node, you can write it as an service, and tie it together using a Message Broker like Beanstalk / ZeroMQ / RabbitMQ.

This allows for ease of deployment, as suitable server resources can be provisioned for the app. In your case, the frontend TCP server can sit on its own cheap instance, while the Tree wrangling program can have a large memory instance to work with.

Also, MongoDB is horrible for relational data, which makes it a bad choice for storing Trees. Graph databases might work for you depending on your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can look into [graph databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database)? [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) seems to be a popular one these days and they have node.js client libraries.

Comment: Hmm, I took a quick look at Neo4j... maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't look like it makes it easy to extract data as a tree?  I basically want to do what this guy wants, and it sounds like he didn't get a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120002/returning-an-entire-hierarchy-tree-using-neo4j-cypher